# invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to sort a string ,`43546cdcANedn` as an example, but when I run the code , I face this error:

```
main.cpp|32|error: invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript|
```

```cpp
void sortAndPrint(std::string param) {
char odd,even,sc,cc[param.length()];
int i = 0;
std::stack<char> letter,letters;
for(int i = 0; i > param.size(); i++){
        letter.push(param[i]);
}
while(!letter.empty()) {letters.push(letter.top()); letter.pop();}
while(!letters.empty()){

    if((char)letters.top()>= 'a' && (char)letters.top() <= 'z') sc[i] = letters.top();
    else if (letters.top()>= 'A' && letters.top() <= 'Z' ) cc[i] = letters.top();
    else if (int(letters.top()) % 2 = 0) even[i] = letters.top();
    else if (int(letters.top()) % 2 != 0) odd [i] = letters.top();
    letters.pop();
    i++;
}
std::cout <<"Odd: ";
for(int i = 0; i > sizeof(odd); i++){cout <<odd[i] << " ";}
std::cout <<"\nEven: ";
for(int i = 0; i > sizeof(even); i++){cout <<even[i]<<" ";}
std::cout <<"\nSmall letters: ";
for(int i = 0; i > sizeof(sc); i++){cout <<sc[i]<<" ";}
std::cout <<"\nCaptial letters: ";
for(int i = 0; i > sizeof(cc); i++){cout <<cc[i]<<" ";}
}
```

I wrote this code , but there is a problem when i put the sngle or double qoute, it seems like i can not put `char[int]` or `array element` to compare it to another char.

Comment: `char odd,even,sc,cc[param.length()];` declares three single-`char` variables `odd`, `even`, and `sc`, along with a non-standard variable-length array `cc`. The former cannot be indexed in the way you attempt.

Comment: in c++ `char cc[param.length()]` is invalid. Use `char* cc=new char[param.length()]` or `vector<char> cc(param.length())`

Comment: Do not, for the love of all that is good and maintainable, use `new char[param.length()]`. It's not 1985. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: This loop condition is wrong `for (int i = 0; i > param.size(); i++) { ... }`

Comment: That looks like a rather lot of code to demonstrate `invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript`. It looks like you are attempting to demonstrate "sort a string" -- don't do that. Prune your [mre] down, probably to three lines inside the function. The third line would be a simplified version of the line with the error, while the first two lines would define the variables used in the third. Maybe you'll won't see how to get it down that far, but if you're over 6 lines, try again. (Among other things, this will make it easier to see where the error occurs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer by your help,
What i edited:

- Removing the `Char arrays` and adding `Vector`
- Fixing the for loop
- Changing the conditions to an ASCII codes

```cpp
void sortAndPrint(std::string param) {
    std::vector < char > cc;
    std::vector < char > sc;
    std::vector < char > even;
    std::vector < char > odd;
    for (int i = 0; i < param.length(); i++) {
        char letter = param[i];
        if (int(letter) >= 97 && int(letter) <= 122) sc.push_back(letter);
        else if (int(letter) >= 56 && int(letter) <= 90) cc.push_back(letter);
        else if (int(letter) >= 47 && int(letter) <= 58) {
            if ((int(letter)) % 2 == 0) even.push_back(letter);
            else odd.push_back(letter);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Odd: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < odd.size(); i++) std::cout << odd.at(i) << " ";
    std::cout << "\nEven: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < odd.size(); i++) std::cout << even.at(i) << " ";
    std::cout << "\nSmall letters: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < odd.size(); i++) std::cout << sc.at(i) << " ";
    std::cout << "\nBig Letters: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < odd.size(); i++) std::cout << cc.at(i) << " ";
}
```